# Can I put a value in a y-series to prevent matplotlib plotting a value for that x-value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have about 15 series which I wish to scatter plot against a series of values of X.

However, for some values in my series I don't want anything to be plotted. Is there a value I can use as a dummy, so that series lengths are the same, but matplotlib won't plot that point?

For example if I have `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` as my x axis, and I have a series on the Y axis `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', foo, 'g','h','i']` and  I don't want to plot foo against 6, I'd like to replace foo with some value that won't be plotted.

I should point out that my x and y values are datetimes. I wasn't expecting that to be necessary info, but it seems that whilst a NaN works for plotting floats, it doesn't work for datetimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this, I used Nones as dummy values, and created

```
def find_indices(haystack, needle):
  return [i for i,x in enumerate(haystack) if needle == x]

def remove_at(xs, indices):
  return [x for i,x in enumerate(xs) if i not in indices]
```

And then

```
nones_at = find_indices(y_values, None)
x_values = remove_at(x_axis, nones_at)
y_values = remove_at(y_values, nones_at)
pyplot.plot(x_values, y_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

`scatter` will ignore the value `numpy.nan` ("not a number").

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from numpy import nan
>>> x = range(5)
>>> y = [10, nan, 15, 14, 12]
>>> plt.scatter(x, y)
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't ignore them when the other values are datetimes; it chokes on a toordinal not being defined on float.

Comment: I agree that you should use np.nan. Another suggestion would be to use a masked array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `None`:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot( [1,2,None,4,5],[1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5],'ro' )
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x29f6d50>]
>>> plt.show()
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `plot_date` and pass in `visible=False`, it will set the axes as if the series was plotted, but will hide the plot so the data points don't show.

If interested, you can see the method `multi_plot_data_with_dates` [here](https://github.com/cperler/trading/blob/master/plot.py)  -- I believe I had the same problem as explained, and this implementation seems to do the trick.